# How to check if file is still being copied in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

How to check if file is still being copied in bash?
How to check the progress of copy operation in bash?

Thank you!

P.S. I'm copying a file via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, not over the  Bash.

Comment: Where are you doing ctrl+c, ctrl+v? Why you want to check in bash?

Comment: Check file size of source and destination?

Comment: I need to check if the file is done copying before doing something with it (in bash)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function check
{
oldsize=`wc -c <"$f"`
sleep 1
newsize=`wc -c <"$f"`

while [ "$oldsize" -lt "$newsize" ]
do
 echo "The file is growing... "
oldsize=`wc -c <"$f"`
sleep 1
newsize=`wc -c <"$f"`
done

if [ "$oldsize" -eq "$newsize" ]
then
   echo "The copying is done!"
fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `md5sum`?

Check current file:

```
$ md5sum bigfile.img 
cd573cfaace07e7949bc0c46028904ff  bigfile.img`
```

Start copy and check *during* copy process:

```
$ cp bigfile.img /tmp/
$ md5sum /tmp/bigfile.img
8e516a451c4b3c440d7bf9aebc5f3639  /tmp/bigfile.img
```

And check after copy finished:

```
$ md5sum /tmp/bigfile.img 
cd573cfaace07e7949bc0c46028904ff  /tmp/bigfile.img
```

Then you can use something like:

```
S_SUM=$(md5sum bigfile.img | cut -d " " -f 1)
D_SUM=$(md5sum /tmp/bigfile.img | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

And compare two `$SUM` variables in some `while true; do` loop.

Another way - using `cmp` and exit code:

```
$ cmp -b bigfile.img /tmp/bigfile.img; echo $?
0

$ cmp -b bigfile.img /tmp/qtsingleapp-homese-8faf-3e8-lockfile &> /dev/null; echo $?
1
```

Comment: check md5sum is quite expensive, is there any other (simpler) way to check if file had been copied completely?

Comment: @user3027198 Added a second way to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way for this - just compare md5sum of files or file sizes like that

```
#!/bin/sh
SOURCE_SIZE=$(stat -c%s source_file)
DEST_SIZE=$(stat -c%s destination_file)
if [[ "$SOURCE_SIZE" -eq "$DEST_SIZE" ]]; then
    echo '..........'
fi
```

Comment: check md5sum is quite expensive, is there any other (simpler) way to check if file had been copied completely? maybe checking it the file size is still changing?

Comment: yep, you can keep in some variable size of destination file and compare it with current value of size or with size of source file